# Database collation w.r.t Spring DATA REST project

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an application being built on Spring DATA and Spring DATA REST platform (Using Spring Boot). Hibernate is the JPA provider and SQL Server 2008 database.

Further, we have alphanumberic ID columns and so, with case insensitive DB collation, the entity with ID "a123" is treated the same as "A123".

So, if I have a table called Employee with the ID as "a123" then, I get the below results:

```
{
  "employeeID" : "a123",
  "links" : [ ],
  "content" : [ ],
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost/spring/Employee/a123{?projection}"
  }, {
    "rel" : "employeeGroups",
    "href" : "http://localhost/spring/Employee/a123/employeeGroups"
  } ]
}
```

And the same thing with ID "A123" as below

```
{
  "employeeID" : "A123",
  "links" : [ ],
  "content" : [ ],
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost/spring/Employee/A123{?projection}"
  }, {
    "rel" : "employeeGroups",
    "href" : "http://localhost/spring/Employee/A123/employeeGroups"
  } ]
}
```

To an end user both the above results are the same and isnt a big deal in having  case insensitive ID.

So far so good. But, when I hit the URL http://localhost/spring/Employee/A123/employeeGroups, i get the list of employeeGroups.. but the same thing doesnt happen with http://localhost/spring/Employee/a123/employeeGroups..  (The actual value stored in the table is "A123").

Im not sure if there is a way to attach a DB collation value to Hibernate or have Spring DATA REST interfaces to always convert the user input value to Upper case before querying the DB.

Please help.

Thanks!